# VBA: ADODB recordset - SQL query return value - convert to number returned in a function

Tags: sql, vba, function, adodb

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT fieldAge FROM tbl1 WHERE fieldName = 'Aaron'
```

It will always return just 1 number.

I want the number to be the return value in a function - getting error on that line.

Thanks!

```
Function getAge(thisName as String) As Double
    Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL as string
    Dim strSomething as string

    strSQL = "SELECT fieldAge FROM tbl1 WHERE fieldName = 'Aaron'"

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connetion
    cn.ConnectionString = {connection string here}
    cn.open
    rs.open strSQL, cn
    While Not rs.EOF
        strSomething = rs!fieldAge
    Wend
    'rs.Close
    cn.Close
    'Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

    getAge = rs.Field(0).Value  // Doesn't work

End Function
```

Comment: your recordset is closed.

Answer (score 1):

No, you've closed the recordset and that's why that line fails..

You've done everything else right except for returning the variable whose scope lived through the RS open/close and stored the SQL result.

`getAge = strSomething`

Also note that `rs.Field(0).Value` and `rs!fieldAge` are the same because fieldAge is the only column you're selecting and it's index is 0 in the fields array.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply!  Sorry, pasting mistake - had commented out the rs close.  the last line still doesn't work though. I think it's not converting the rs value to a number/double?

Comment: Uncomment and follow my advice.